# How to get rid of horizontal scrollbar in Material-UI TreeView?

Tags: material-ui

When trying out the Material-UI basic example for Tree View (@mui/lab/TreeView), I do not know how to remove the horizontal scrollbar when using the `overflowY: "auto"` (The same effect even if I use `overflow: "auto"`) option in the `sx` prop of the `TreeView` component. The horizontal scrollbar appears no matter how much space is available to the right. I want to keep the `overflowY` option in case of vertical overflow.

[image]

For example please see the basic tree view example from the official [Material-UI page](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tree-view/#main-content) in StackBlitz or CodeSandbox.

How to remove the horizontal scrollbar when it's not needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the CSS classes `.MuiTreeItem-content` and its child `.MuiTreeItem-label` are set to 100% width by default, therefore, the `.MuiTreeItem-content`'s 8px padding on x axis (also default) get in the way, adding 16px too many. You can easily override this by setting `.MuiTreeItem-content`'s class padding to 0.

```js
// ...

import MuiTreeItem from "@mui/lab/TreeItem";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const TreeItem = styled(MuiTreeItem)(({ theme }) => ({
  "& .MuiTreeItem-content": {
    padding: 0,
  },
}));

// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the horizontal scrollbar completely you can hide the overflow over the X axis.

in css

```css
.TreeView {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

or in jsx

```js
  <TreeView
     sx={{ overflowX: "hidden" }}
     ...
  >
```